# не могу разобраться с 2 запросами по sql

Tags: mysql

Есть 3 таблицы:

**competition**

```
competition_id (ID соревнования);
competition_name (наименование соревнования);
world_record (мировой рекорд);
set_date (дата установки мирового рекорда);
```

**result**

```
competition_id (ID соревнования);
sportsman_id (ID спортсмена);
result (результат спортсмена);
city (место проведения);
hold_date (дата проведения);
```

**sportsman**

```
sportsman_id (ID спортсмена);
sportsman_name (имя спортсмена);
rank (разряд спортсмена);
year_of_birth (год рождения);
personal_record (персональный рекорд);
country (страна спортсмена);
```

Осталось 2 запроса выполнить, ну что-то они никак не срабатывают :

**Найдите минимальный разряд спортсменов, которые установили мировой рекорд.**

**Выведите названия соревнований, на которых было установлено максимальное количество мировых рекордов.**

По поводу запроса про минимальный разряд, вот что я попробовал написать, ну не сработало - select min(rank) from sportsman s join result r on s.sportsman_id = r.sportsman_id join competition c on c.competition_id = r.competition_id where result < world_record;

По поводу второго запроса, как то идей нет.

Comment: По 1) - сперва выведите всех рекордсменов с их разрядами; по 2) - сперва выведите все рекорды и соотв. соревнования.

Answer (score 0):

Первая запись в запросе и будет искомый результат:

```
SELECT country, count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY country) AS quantity FROM sportsman
JOIN result ON result.sportsman_id = sportsman.sportsman_id
JOIN competition ON competition.competition_id = result.competition_id
ORDER BY quantity DESC
```

ПС Не уверен в валидности MySQL

Comment: OVER(PARTITION BY country) - это не валидно увы

Comment: ну тогда вместо OVER используйте GROUP BY, но здесь запрос малехо переписать нужно